# how to avoid common tern in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST(c#) client to play with elasticsearch in which when i search question like "how to find a " it will provide the result which contain max-hits for words like *to* and *a* . 
how can avoid search words like  a , to, is , are, was etc. this is my code sample

```
var Result = client.Search(q => q
               .Index(IndexName)
               .From(0)
               .Type("table")
               .Size(10)
               .Fields("title","description")
               .QueryString(searchWord))
```

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping you really were having trouble with a [common tern](http://birds.audubon.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/bird-full/species_images/Common_Tern_m17-69-048_l.jpg). Now that would've made for an interesting question. But I guess that's a typo after all.

Comment: Look for "stopword". There are analyzers that filter those out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NEST version 1.0 they implemented this.
You can do it by adding this line to your search I guess.

```
.Query(b => b.CommonTerms(c => c.CutOffFrequency(0.1)))
```

I have not been able to test this but I hope it helps. 
More info can be found here: (elasticsearch 1.0)
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html#query-dsl-common-terms-query 
and here: (release nodes NEST 1.0)
http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/introducing-elasticsearch-net-nest-1-0-0-beta1/